# Getting blank response for $util methods in AWS API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, mocking, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I am trying to generate a UUID for mocking purposes in the AWS API gateway.

```
#set($myValue = "$util.autoId()")
##Prints '5'
$myValue
{"abc" : "$myValue"}
```

Here is a snapshot of the integration response.

[image]

But I am getting a blank response for this code.

[image]

Same issue with all other $util functions.

**How to generate random UUID without using lambda**.

Answer (score 2):

I generated UUID from request-id

```
$context.requestId
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be trying to use an option that is available for mappings with AppSync.  `$util.autoId` is available there: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html

But for API Gateway, the `$util` options are different: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#util-template-reference

So `autoId` isn't an available option, and none of the other API Gateway variables and functions look like they'll get you a UUID directly without it coming from the input somehow (like context or parameters).

Comment: I managed to get UUID from request-id. ie **$context.requestId**